# Can Mellin transform be applied in this function? What's the result?

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, fourier-transform, integral-transforms, laplace-transform

$$f(x) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{T \to \infty } {i}\int_{-1/2-i\,T}^{-1/2+i\,T} \frac{(x-1)^{s}}{2^{s+1}}\,\frac{1}{sin(\pi*s)\,}\,\frac{ds}{s}$$

Answer (score 1):

If I rewrite the integral in the usual form of an inverse Mellin transform, I get:
$$-\frac{1}{2\pi}f(x+1)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{1/2-i\infty}^{1/2+i\infty}x^{-s}2^{1-s}\frac{1}{\sin\pi s}\frac{ds}{s}=\frac{2}{\pi} \ln \left(\frac{1}{2 x}+1\right)$$

Comment: Is this formula right? Εxample for x = 12 something goes wrong. May be the first term, is -2/Pi*f(4x+1) = 1/(2*Pi*i).... and not -1/(2Pi)*f(x+1)?